# Laravel Pint code style schema for PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, coding-style, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, laravel-pint

**How to set up PhpStorm code style (Code alignment) to work with [Laravel Pint](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pint)?**

**Is there a scheme for Pint Code Style and code alignment in a file?**

**Does PhpStorm's Laravel Code Style is up to date?**

The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pint#presets) says that it uses Laravel preset.

*By default, Pint uses the Laravel preset, which fixes issues by following the opinionated coding style of Laravel.*

But, when I set the Code style from Laravel, some fixes are made again by Pint.

[image]

###### Example:

Laravel default:

```
(!$var)
```

Pint:

```
(! $var)
```

Is there some set of rules or schema for PhpStorm to work the same as Pint?

Comment: As I can see, there's no such thing as Pint Code Style, as Pint is simply a tool. Perhaps you can use an IDE editorconfig integration (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-code-style.html#EditorConfig) and add this editorconfig file to your project: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/.editorconfig

Comment: @Dmitrii *"...as Pint is simply a tool"* But it has own rules/config -- Laravel ones. From https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pint -- *"By default, Pint does not require any configuration and will fix code style issues in your code **by following the opinionated coding style of Laravel**."* Based on the screenshot/code fragment, the question might be -- "does PhpStorm's Laravel Code Style is up to date?"

Comment: @LazyOne good question. My PhpStorm version is 2022.1.4 (Updated yesterday), so I'll update my question too with your observation.

Comment: @mare96 *"Is there a scheme for Pint Code Style and code alignment in a file?"* No. And TBH unlikely to be (since Pint uses Laravel rules). The same as why you do not see PHP-CS-Fixer schema there. So you will have to use `Set from... | Laravel` and adjust any differences there by manually changing the most appropriate options.

Comment: @mare96 Then you can **try** using a Pint instead of PHP-CS-Fixer at `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | PHP | Quality Tools`. That's if they both use the same parameters of course (have not used Pint yet, so do not know). If that's not the case, consider making a Feature Request ticket at the PhpStorm Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI **P.S.** You may integrate it using External Tools (manual invocation) or File Watcher (automatic on save) -- try and see how it will work.

Comment: Enable pint in phpStorm on save action: https://gilbitron.me/blog/running-laravel-pint-in-phpstorm/